# How to fill pandas dataframe columns in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy

I'm trying to fill `pandas` dataframe columns in a for loop. The column name is parametric and assigned by loop value. This is my code:

```
for k in range (-1, -4, -1):
    df_orj = pd.read_csv('something.csv', sep= '\t') 

    df_train = df_orj.head(11900)   
    df_test = df_orj.tail(720) 

    SHIFT = k

    df_train.trend = df_train.trend.shift(SHIFT)
    df_train = df_train.dropna()
    df_test.trend = df_test.trend.shift(SHIFT)
    df_test = df_test.dropna()

    drop_list = some_list

    df_out = df_test[['date','price']]
    df_out.index = np.arange(0, len(df_out)) # start index from 0
    df_out["pred-1"] = np.nan
    df_out["pred-2"] = np.nan
    df_out["pred-3"] = np.nan

    df_train.drop(drop_list, 1, inplace = True )
    df_test.drop(drop_list, 1, inplace = True )

    # some processes here

    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10)
    rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)
    print("accuracy score: " , rf.score(X_test, y_test))


    X_test2 = sc.transform(df_test.drop('trend', axis=1))
    y_test2 = df_test['trend'].values

    y_pred2  = rf.predict(X_test2)
    print("accuracy score: ",rf.score(X_test2, y_test2))


    name = "pred{0}".format(k)
    for i in range (0, y_test2.size):
        df_out[name][i] = y_pred2[i]

df_out.head(20)
```

And this is my output:

```
                time_period_start  price_open  pred-1  pred-2  pred-3
697  2018-10-02T02:00:00.0000000Z       86.80     NaN     NaN     1.0
698  2018-10-02T03:00:00.0000000Z       86.65     NaN     NaN     1.0
699  2018-10-02T04:00:00.0000000Z       86.32     NaN     NaN     1.0
```

As you can see, only `pred-3` is filled. How can I fill all 3 pre-defined columns?

Comment: You’re re-initializing those columns to go null in your for loop. Move your df_out[“pred-1”] = np.nan to before your for loop

Comment: @chitown88 Oh, that's silly of me. Since I re-initialize the columns, I lose first 2 column information. Can you post the correct code as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Yup. No worries. Easy brain fart...happens all the time. I think we all do that at one time or another. I can guarantee I’ll make that mistake again too in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting those 3 columns as nulls in each loop, so you’re losing those values as it iterates. Either move those initializing columns to before the loop, or you could just initialize with variables with:

Change out

```
df_out["pred-1"] = np.nan
df_out["pred-2"] = np.nan
df_out["pred-3"] = np.nan
```

To just initialize the individual column as it loops

```
name = "pred{0}".format(k)
df_out[name] = np.nan
```

So full code:

```
for k in range (-1, -4, -1):
    df_orj = pd.read_csv('something.csv', sep= '\t') 

    df_train = df_orj.head(11900)   
    df_test = df_orj.tail(720) 

    SHIFT = k

    df_train.trend = df_train.trend.shift(SHIFT)
    df_train = df_train.dropna()
    df_test.trend = df_test.trend.shift(SHIFT)
    df_test = df_test.dropna()

    drop_list = some_list

    df_out = df_test[['date','price']]
    df_out.index = np.arange(0, len(df_out)) # start index from 0

    name = "pred{0}".format(k)
    df_out[name] = np.nan

    df_train.drop(drop_list, 1, inplace = True )
    df_test.drop(drop_list, 1, inplace = True )

    # some processes here

    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10)
    rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)
    print("accuracy score: " , rf.score(X_test, y_test))


    X_test2 = sc.transform(df_test.drop('trend', axis=1))
    y_test2 = df_test['trend'].values

    y_pred2  = rf.predict(X_test2)
    print("accuracy score: ",rf.score(X_test2, y_test2))



    for i in range (0, y_test2.size):
        df_out[name][i] = y_pred2[i]

df_out.head(20)
```

Comment: I moved the columns out of the loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If i am understanding correctly, then your issue is that you are getting pred-3 
filled only where as other two are nan.
It's because your df_out is in the loop and you are getting the results for last 
iteration of loop. 
You should define it outside the loop so that you information won't get lost for 
the other two.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is the same with @chitown88's.